# How do I make a View with borderRadius transparent?

Tags: react-native, view

I have a `<KeyboardAvoidingView />`, to which I added borderRadius on the top left and right. I want it at the bottom of the screen. This `<KeyboardAvoidingView />` is on top of a `<FlatList />`. However adding rounded borders leaves a gray shadow. The only way I managed to make them disappear and be transparent the way I wish (so you can see the `<FlatList />` behind), was to use `position: "absolute"`, but then its no longer a keyboard avoiding View.

```
const StoreItems = ({route}) => {
  const stores = useStores();
  const [store, setStore] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setStore(stores[route.params.storeId]);
  });

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flatList: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
    view: {
      height: 60,
      borderRadius: 40,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
  });


    return (
      <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <FlatList
          data={store.items}
          renderItem={item => {
            return <ListItem item={item} />;
          }}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          style={styles.flatList}></FlatList>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.view} />
      </View>
    );
};
```

The gray shadows left by the View

[image: The gray shadows left by the View]

Comment: can you try like this <KeyboardAvoidingView contentContainerStyle={styles.view} />

Comment: No that doesnt really change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set FlatList‘s container view backgroundColor ([sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/set-container-view-background-color)).

Comment: That changes the color, but I still can't make it transparent, it just all turn into gray. I want the <FlatList /> items to be seen through the gap left by the <KeyboardSafeView /> being rounded.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot from my sample and mark the gap?

Comment: Can you try to explain what you want in other words?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Cedj3cVdvtJWvXoo7 Here, this is what I wish it would look like. You can see the items of the FlatList behind the View on top of it

Comment: I have updated my sample